# Extracting all lines based on means of two column using Regex on postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to extract all lines with meaning of two columns is different or not based on a regex in postgresql.

Example :

```
col1                    | col2         | result
------------------------+--------------+-----------------------
teste 1452-251-99 azert | 1425-251-99  | Same meaning
teste 1225-71-45        | 1225--71.45  | Same meaning
teste 1288-91-75        | 1225--71.45  | Not the same meaning
```

The format of column col2 must be `\d{3,6}-\d{3}-\d{2}`, and I consider this column is the correct value

I couldn't find the correct query, and this is my attempt:

```
update my_table 
set result = 'Not the same meaning' 
where id in (select t.id from my_table t
             where col1 ~'\d{3,6}-\d{3}-\d{2}' 
               and col1 not like format('%%%s%%', col2)
);
```

but this returns only where the two columns are not the same

```
col1                    | col2         | result
------------------------+--------------+-----------------------
teste 1452-251-99 azert | 1425-251-99  | Not the same meaning
teste 1225-71-45        | 1225--71.45  | Not the same meaning
teste 1288-91-75        | 1225--71.45  | Not the same meaning
```

Comment: Does `col1` only contains a single occurrence of the pattern?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Yes

Comment: Good, then the solution in my answer should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest mingling both columns before coparing them using a regex replace so that only the formated number remains:

```
update my_table 
set result = 'Not the same meaning' 
where id in (select t.id from my_table t
             where 
             REGEXP_REPLACE(col1, '^.*\y(\d{3,6})\D+?(\d{2,3})\D+?(\d{2})\y.*$', '\1-\2-\3') 
             != REGEXP_REPLACE(col2, '^.*\y(\d{3,6})\D+?(\d{2,3})\D+?(\d{2})\y.*$', '\1-\2-\3')
);
```

Note: The syntax assumes PG v7.4+.

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ohHBG1kB6knyQXvwae2ofx/1) is a db-fiddle that shows it in action.

Comment: it gives me a wrong output, anyway I found the solution and I post it, Thank you wp78de for your help

Comment: @khelilimiliana however, it was working with the demo data you provided as demonstrated. I suspect there some differently formated that is not covered by your samples.

Comment: Yes yes, You was right after all, I upvoted and accepted your answer, even I think that my answer is the most acceptable answer (Please see it) your comment will be helpfull for all community, but your answer deserve to be accepted, Thankyou wp78de.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace all special chars in between digits in `col2` with a `-` hyphen, and then check using regex if there is a match of this pattern within word boundaries:

```sql
where col1 ~'\d{3,6}-\d{3}-\d{2}' 
and 
col1 !~ CONCAT('\y', REGEXP_REPLACE(col2, '(?<=\d)[^[:space:]0-9]+(?=\d)', '-', 'g'), '\y')
```

For the `1225--71.45` value in `col2`, the `CONCAT('\y', REGEXP_REPLACE(col2, '(?<=\d)[^[:space:]0-9]+(?=\d)', '-', 'g'), '\y')` part will yield `\y1225-71-45\y`, and it will match `1225-71-45` as a "whole word", when not enclosed with word chars. See the [`(?<=\d)[^[:space:]0-9]+(?=\d)` regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/c243H8/1).

Comment: I got this error `argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text`, I think the errot was `col1 !~ '\y'`

Comment: @khelilimiliana OK, try with `CONCAT`. Add `where` before `col1 !~` if necessary.

Comment: I got another problem and I failled to resolve it `invalid regular expression: parentheses () not balanced`

Comment: @khelilimiliana Use `(?<=\d)[^[:space:]0-9]+(?=\d)`, do not introduce any more parentheses.

Comment: I didn't understand why is still show me the same error, if I delete the first `[` it works but wrong value

Comment: Thank you for your help, I upvoted your answer, and I will try to resolve the problem.

Comment: @khelilimiliana Do not remove `[` in `[^[:space:]0-9]`, it is a negated bracket expression that matches any char but whitespace and digit. You may replace it with `[[:punct:][:alpha:]]`. You may try with `REGEXP_REPLACE(col2, '(\d)[[:punct:][:alpha:]]+(?=\d)', '\1-', 'g')`

Comment: I didn't remove the first braket, but after googling the error msg, I found that postgres use posix syntax in regex, and it doesn't accept the query, any way I found the solution and I post it, Thank you for your help Wiktor.

Comment: @khelilimiliana PostgreSQL supports AREs that support all lookarounds, you must be using some very old version.

Comment: Version of My postgresql is 9.6

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have found the solution, I extract all number from the two columns, then I check if `col2` is substring of `col1`

```
select id, col2, col1, res_col2, res_col1 from
(select t.id, col2, col1, regexp_replace(col2, '\D','','g')::numeric::varchar as res_col2, 
regexp_replace(col1, '\D','','g')::numeric::varchar as res_col1
 from my_table t
inner join fleet_col1 fv on t.col1_id = fv.id
where col1 ~'\d{3,6}-\d{3}-\d{2}' and 
NULLIF(regexp_replace(col2, '\D','','g'), '')::numeric::varchar not like NULLIF(regexp_replace(col1, '\D','','g'), '')::numeric::varchar

) tab1
where res_col1 not like '%' || res_col2|| '%';
```

`regexp_replace(col2, '\D','','g')::numeric::varchar` ==> Extract digit from string,
Ex `123;:/-456ffrg6787` ===> `1234566787`

`::numeric::varchar` ===> to eliminate the meaningless 0, then cast the result to `varchar` for comparison.

I make condition `where regexp_replace ...` in first subquery to eliminate the error `invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""` if col2/col1 does not contain a number.

`where res_col1 not like '%' || res_col2|| '%'` check if result of col1 is substring of the first result col2.

Note. I use `select` instead of `update` just to see my result